# How can i make my CNN output a vector of features

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I'm working on a project and i need to make my CNN output like the output of the "Flatten" Layer.
No classification just a vector of input photo features, and I'm kind of lost... i know every thing about CNN structure but how can i start doing this with python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another alternative is the following.

Imagine you have a tf Keras model (here I take a small one for the sake of simplicity).

```py
>>> model.summary()

Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 128)               100480
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 64)                8256
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 32)                2080
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 33
=================================================================
Total params: 110,849
Trainable params: 110,849
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Let's say you want a $32$-long feature vector, corresponding to the layer `dense_3`.

now you can create another object

```py
outputs = model.get_layer('dense_3').output
child_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs = model.inputs, outputs= outputs)
```

and your child model does what you want. You need to call

```py
features = child_model.predict(image)
```

**Important note:** If you print `model.layers` and `child_model.layers` you will not be surprised they share the same layers at the same memory addresses. This means training one will set the layers weights of the other.

Comment: thank you very much for this helpful method, but i have just one question, do i have to train my model before i start extract features or no?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Keras? If you are, you can take a look here for examples (https://keras.io/api/applications/#extract-features-with-vgg16).

Basically, you do

```
features = model.predict(x)
np.save(outfile, features) # outfile is your desire output filename
```

you can load back the file using

```
features = np.load(outfile)
```